# Storing radio button values in an array ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an online test which displays questions in a partial view as shown here:

http://i52.photobucket.com/albums/g28/conor2099/example.png

The question image and 5 associated radio buttons are called in a foreach loop. The relevant section of code from the view is:

**View:**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="span5 offset5">
        <div class="row">

            @foreach (var item in Model.questions)
            {
                ViewBag.Name = item.question1;     

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="question">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(@item.question1)" style="position:absolute; left:600px;" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="rdioPos" style="position:absolute; left:600px;">
                        <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name=@ViewBag.Name value="1"> 1</label>
                        <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name=@ViewBag.Name value="2"> 2</label>
                        <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name=@ViewBag.Name value="3"> 3</label>
                        <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name=@ViewBag.Name value="4"> 4</label>
                        <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name=@ViewBag.Name value="5"> 5</label>              
                    </div>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">


                </script>
            }
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>

 <div class="row">
        <div class="span5" style="position:absolute; top:450px; left:1100px">
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Next", "Next", new { id = @ViewData["scenNo"]},

        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET", // HttpMethod to use, GET or POST
            UpdateTargetId = "divScenarios", // ID of the HTML element to update
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace // Replace the existing contents
        }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the next button is clicked I want to read the value in each set of buttons, store in an array and pass to the controller in order to update a database. The partial view is updated also.

Here is the method from the controller:

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult Next(int id)
    {

        id = id + 1;

        if (id > noOfScens)
            id = 1;

        scenario scenario = db.scenarios.Find(id);
        ViewData["scenNo"] = id;
        return PartialView("_Scen", scenario);
    }
```

and here is the scenario model:

**Model**

```
namespace TestingApp.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class scenario
{
    public scenario()
    {
        this.questions = new HashSet<question>();
    }

    public int scenario_id { get; set; }
    public string scenario1 { get; set; }
    public string scenario_type { get; set; }
    public int scenario_group_id { get; set; }
    public List<int> ansVals { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<question> questions { get; set; }
}
```

}

Can this be done or do I need to rethink my approach? I have tried all I can think of and am very stuck for time. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to write some Javascript, but yes, I imagine that it could be done.

Comment: I would say you have to create the logic doing a foreach loop on the controller. I am not sure if you can pass that as a viewmodel directly to the controller. should be manually parsed. but the approach is interesting.

Comment: If your out of ideas... Check to see how EF would handle the questions. Make test table and import it using database first. It might be a bad database design to have all the bools in there but at least it will give you an idea.

Comment: I think you can use Session